# How to set function return value or dynamic data to angular state custom data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

I have trouble in some angular code that is i want to set dynamic data to angular state custom data. Here is my code

```
function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('apps', {
            parent: 'entity',
            url: '/apps',       
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],//i want to set dynamic data or return data here
                pageTitle: 'smsApp.apps.home.title'                     
            },           
            views: {
                 'nav@':{
                    templateUrl: 'app/layouts/navbar/navbar.html',
                    controller: 'NavbarController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                },'leftnav@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/layouts/leftnavbar/leftnavbar.html',
                    controller: 'LeftNavbarController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                },
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/entities/apps/apps.html',
                    controller: 'AppsController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('apps');
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
                    return $translate.refresh();
                }]

            }
        })
```

Above the code, I want to set dynamic function or data in

```
data: {
                authorities: dynamic data or funciton,//i want to set dynamic data or return data here
                pageTitle: 'smsApp.apps.home.title'                     
            }
```

So, somebody help me who will know that

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should declare an anonymous function that returns data.For example:

```
data: {
            authorities: function(){ return data }
            pageTitle: 'smsApp.apps.home.title'                     
        },
```

Edit: If you want the data to be automatically extracted on route declaration, you can go this way:

```
    data: {
            authorities: (function(){ return data })()
            pageTitle: 'smsApp.apps.home.title'                     
        },
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, I already try that, but when i call the data like that data: {
            authorities: function(){ return 'test'}
            pageTitle: 'smsApp.apps.home.title'                     
        }and when i log with console.log($state.$current.data.authorities), result is function (){
                    return 'test';
                } how should i do

Comment: what value shown for `console.log($state.$current.data.authorities())`? @KyawZinHtun